# Can the value of a primary key be the same as another column in the same row?

Tags: sql

I have a table with primary key, route number, as 'FBN001' and a foreign key, flight number, with the same value 'FBN001'. Is this allowed?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. Your foreign key is a different field that points to the primary key of another table. You just cannot have the same values in your primary key columns.

Answer (score 1):

The value of primary key need to be unique with respect to other values in the same column. If the value of another column is the same I think that it work. But in another row on the value of primary key there cannot bE 'FBN001'.